# Move file from Chrome File System folder to another directory (in Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I have a task to move a file stored in Chrome internal folder to another directory (user should choose final location). I wrote some code to read file from File System and show "Save File" dialog, but I don't know how to handle successful saving and cancel events to remove initial file. Do you have any suggestions?

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile("my file", {}, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = 'display: none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'my file';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

            //remove file after successful saving
            //or remove it immediately if user clicked cancel

        }, fsErrorHandler);
    }, fsErrorHandler);
}

window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, videoSize, onInitFs, fsErrorHandler);
```

Comment: Maybe you'll have to use chrome.downloads API.

Comment: @wOxxOm file is already on my local computer and chrome.downloads API  provides network oriented downloading features. Unfortunately it's not suitable for my case.

Comment: Use a blob: [Save Data URI as file using downloads.download() API](//stackoverflow.com/a/40279050)

Comment: @wOxxOm very promising solution! Thank you very much. I'll try.